# Text Embeddings from Finetuned llama2 model

Tags: python, langchain, llama, peft

I have finetuned my locally loaded llama2 model and saved the adapter weights locally. To load the fine-tuned model,  I first load the base model and then load my peft model like below:

```
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(base_model, peft_model_id)
```

Now, I want to get the text embeddings from my finetuned llama model using LangChain but LlamaCppEmbeddings accepts model_path as an argument not the model. What is the best way to create text embeddings using a loaded model?

```
embeddings = LlamaCppEmbeddings(model_path=llama_model_path, n_ctx=2048)
```

my questions are: 1- how to save my finetuned model (base+peft) not only the PeftModel locally?
2- How can I create text embeddings from my loaded model?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create and persist you embeddings by using any of the vectorstores available in `langchain`. In this example `FAISS` was used.

```py
from langchain.embeddings import LlamaCppEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader, DirectoryLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter



# load pdfs in folder
loader = DirectoryLoader(
    'path/to/pdfs',
    glob='*.pdf',
    loader_cls=PyPDFLoader
)
documents = loader.load()

# split all pdfs
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=1000,
    chunk_overlap=100
)
splits = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

# load CPP llama model
embedder = LlamaCppEmbeddings(model_path="/path/to/fine_tuned_model.bin")

# create faiss vectorstore
vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(
    documents=splits,
    embedding=embedder,
)

# persist locally
vectorstore.save_local('./faiss_vs')

# create chroma vectorstore
# vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(
#    documents=splits,
#    embedding=embedder,
#    persist_directory=str(./chroma_vs)
# )
```